# AES Encryption key generation that is consistent each execution?

Tags: java, encryption

I found this well written example of how to use AES encryption, and I will admit some of the more advanced aspects are beyond me. The class works fine, provided I'm using the same instance object. If I create another object, using the same exact passPhrase - that object can no longer properly decode any kind of string or data that the previous object created. I can only conclude that since this code takes the rather weak passPhrase string, mixes SALT, and builds a stronger 128-bit key - that this process of key construction is somehow randomized each time around. The significance being:

```
new AESEncrypter("MyPassword") <> new AESEncrypter("MyPassword")
```

Could someone help me modify the class below to get the desired behavior:

```
AESEncrypter a = new AESEncrypter("MyPassword")
String encoded = a.encrypt("my message")

AESEncrypter b = new AESEncrypter("MyPassword")
b.decrypt(encoded) == "my message"
```

```
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

public class AESEncrypter {

    private static final byte[] SALT = {
            (byte) 0xA9, (byte) 0x9B, (byte) 0xC8, (byte) 0x32,
            (byte) 0x56, (byte) 0x35, (byte) 0xE3, (byte) 0x03
    };
    private static final int ITERATION_COUNT = 65536;
    private static final int KEY_LENGTH = 128;
    public Cipher ecipher;
    public Cipher dcipher;

    AESEncrypter(String passPhrase) throws Exception {

    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(passPhrase.toCharArray(), SALT, ITERATION_COUNT, KEY_LENGTH);
        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);

        // I Think the problem is here???

        SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

        ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);

        dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        byte[] iv = ecipher.getParameters().getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
    }

    public String encrypt(String encrypt) throws Exception {
        byte[] bytes = encrypt.getBytes("UTF8");
        byte[] encrypted = encrypt(bytes);
        return new BASE64Encoder().encode(encrypted);
    }

    public byte[] encrypt(byte[] plain) throws Exception {
        return ecipher.doFinal(plain);
    }

    public String decrypt(String encrypt) throws Exception {
        byte[] bytes = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encrypt);
        byte[] decrypted = decrypt(bytes);
        return new String(decrypted, "UTF8");
    }

    public byte[] decrypt(byte[] encrypt) throws Exception {
        return dcipher.doFinal(encrypt);
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String message = "MESSAGE";
        String password = "PASSWORD";

        AESEncrypter encrypter1 = new AESEncrypter(password);
        AESEncrypter encrypter2 = new AESEncrypter(password);

        String encrypted1 = encrypter1.encrypt(message);
        String encrypted2 = encrypter2.encrypt(message);

        System.out.println("Display Encrypted from object 1 and 2..why do they differ?" );

        System.out.println(encrypted1) ;
        System.out.println(encrypted2) ;

        System.out.println("Display Each object decrypting its own encrypted msg. Works as expected" );

        System.out.println(encrypter1.decrypt(encrypted1)) ;
        System.out.println(encrypter2.decrypt(encrypted2)) ;

        System.out.println("Attempt to decrypt the each others msg.. will fail" );

        System.out.println(encrypter1.decrypt(encrypted2)) ;
        System.out.println(encrypter2.decrypt(encrypted1)) ;

    }

}
```

Display Encrypted from object 1 and 2..why do they differ?

```
drGy+BNSHPy34NWkkcNqLQ==

9p06VfBgTuh7TizZSbvKjw==
```

Display Each object decrypting its own encrypted msg. Works as expected

```
MESSAGE

MESSAGE
```

Attempt to decrypt the each others msg.. will fail

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:966)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:824)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:436)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
```

Comment: if the SALT and the passphrase are the same values each time, the result should be the same.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Thanks for checking maybe I have some other bug in my code leading to the data misalignment being produced

Comment: I've updated the example above to show the proven issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you initialize a new `Cipher` in CBC mode, it generates a fresh and random IV for you. This Initialization Vector doesn't have to be secret, but it has to be unpredictable to provide semantic security. You can simply put the IV in front of the ciphertext and use it for decryption.

```
public byte[] encrypt(byte[] plain) throws Exception {
    byte[] iv = ecipher.getParameters().getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
    byte[] ct = ecipher.doFinal(plain);
    byte[] result = new byte[ct.length + iv.length];
    System.arraycopy(iv, 0, result, 0, iv.length);
    System.arraycopy(ct, 0, result, iv.length, ct.length);
    return result;
}

public byte[] decrypt(byte[] encrypt) throws Exception {
    byte[] iv = new byte[dcipher.getBlockSize()];
    byte[] ct = new byte[encrypt.length - dcipher.getBlockSize()];
    System.arraycopy(encrypt, 0, iv, 0, dcipher.getBlockSize());
    System.arraycopy(encrypt, dcipher.getBlockSize(), ct, 0, ct.length);

    dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
    return dcipher.doFinal(ct);
}
```

You will need to store `secret` during the initialization step in a private variable for the decryption to work.

---

Keep in mind that the salt for PBDKF2 should also be random and 16 bytes long. You can store it alongside of the IV.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and code have helped me study AES a bit more to understand what this code is actually doing, and what CBC mode is.  Let's say for example that I make a messaging App that uses the code above where each person has the same AES password. Does it make sense to transmit the IV pre-pended to each message in this way? Perhaps I've chosen the wrong form of AES mode...

Comment: The IV has only one purpose and that is randomizing the ciphertext even if you encrypt the exact same plaintext with exactly the same key. It's called [semantic security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_security). Otherwise, a passive attacker (observer) might determine that you sent the same message again and deduce something from that. If you're using a random salt to derive the key from the password, then you don't need a random IV, but you probably don't want to derive the key each time you encrypt some message, so a random IV makes sense.

Comment: Excellent learning info and the code above worked great, thanks!

Comment: Lol opps didn't realize I could do that and "accept" done, and done =)